# Javascript pick random txt in dir and populate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create something that allows me to have txt documents or a single web page (I can pre-populate this with MYSQL) which has the following data in it:

- Question
- Answer1
- Answer2
- Answer3
- Answer4

Each answer also needs to have a set amount of points associated to it.
I then want to place it into specific div tags in my script, the script goes as the following:

```js
<script>
// PSUEDO:
// If Answer from IRC is found, then run Element change
// Element change pulls from Question - Answer DB
// Else, Play sound.
var div = document.getElementById('Answerone');
div.innerHTML = 'Extra stuff';

var div = document.getElementById('Answertwo');
div.innerHTML = 'Extra stuff';

var div = document.getElementById('Answerthree');
div.innerHTML = 'Extra stuff';

var div = document.getElementById('Answerfour');
div.innerHTML = 'Extra stuff';

// Add all "Points" class together 
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var sum = 0;
 $('.Points').each(function () {
  sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
 });
 $('.total-points').text(sum);
});
</script>
```

```css
body {
    background: url('http://puu.sh/i4hoo/361da54ae9.jpg') no-repeat;
    font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
span {
    margin-top:10px;
}
#Answers {
    padding: 16px 0px;
    margin-left: 240px;
    color: white;
    //background: cyan;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    width: 520px;
}
#Answerone {
    padding: 8px;
    //background: blue;
    width: 434px;
    float:left;
}
#Answertwo {
    padding: 8px;
    //background: blue;
    width: 434px;
    float:left;
}
#Answerthree {
    padding: 8px;
    //background: blue;
    width: 434px;
    float:left;
}
#Answerfour {
    padding: 8px;
    //background: blue;
    width: 434px;
    float:left;
}
#Answerfive {
    padding: 8px;
    //background: blue;
    width: 434px;
    float:left;
}
#Totalpoints {
    padding: 8px;
    //background: blue;
    width: 434px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.Points {
    padding: 8px;
    //background: blue;
    width: 20px;
    float:right;
}
.total-points {
    padding: 8px;
    //background: blue;
    width: 20px;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Answers">
    <div id="Answerone">tests</div>
    <div class="Points">12</div>
    <div id="Answertwo">tests</div>
    <div class="Points">12</div>
    <div id="Answerthree">tests</div>
    <div class="Points">12</div>
    <div id="Answerfour">tests</div>
    <div class="Points">12</div>
    <div id="Answerfive">tests</div>
    <div class="Points">12</div>
    <div id="TotalPoints"></div>
    <div class="total-points">0</div>
</div>
```

The Answers will be hidden at first and will activate if a word is detected (One of the answers). How would I format a Text document to populate the content within divs using `div.innerHTML`?

Comment: Where are you supposed to type an answer?

Comment: Not the question at hand, but the answers will be input via a text box OR if I can get the document to connect to IRC it'l pickup an irc message

Comment: _"How would I format a Text document to populate the content within divs using div.innerHTML?"_ Not certain requirement correctly ? Does "Text document" provide text at "Extra stuff" `div.innerHTML = 'Extra stuff';` ?

Comment: So what's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to take text out of a text document or mysql database or ANYTHING else, and populate the divs using div.innerHTML.

Comment: @BradlySpicer Can include example of _"a text document"_ at Question ? Could "text document" be `text/html` ?

Comment: a text document being a .txt I don't mind what it is, it can be any format.

Comment: @BradlySpicer Tried `js` at post ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use FileReader API to read the text file and then just put the content into your div via `.innerHTML`. You could even have HTML syntax in it if you would like.

```js
// This is just a pseudo text file!
var txtFile = new Blob(['Hello<br />', ' World!']);

var r = new FileReader();

r.onload = function(e) {
  var content = e.target.result;
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerHTML = content;
}

r.readAsText(txtFile);

// You would actually have to load your file first.
/*

var txtFile = "path/to/your/text.txt";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', txtFile, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var blob = this.response;
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onload = function(e) {
      var content = e.target.result;
      var output = document.getElementById('output');
      output.innerHTML = content;
    }
    r.readAsText(blob);
  }
};

xhr.send();


*/
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `text/html` document , `.load()` to populate `div` elements.

`text/html` document

```
<div class="Answerone">
  Extra stuff
</div>
<div class="Answertwo">
  Extra stuff
</div>
<div class="Answerthree">
  Extra stuff
</div>
<div class="Answerfour">
  Extra stuff
</div>
```

`js`

```
$("#Answerone").load("path/to/html/document .Answerone", function () {
  $(this)
  .html(
    $(this)
    .find(".Answerone")
    .html()
  );
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lvb01xey/